# Read command line gradle vars in class

Tags: java, gradle, command-line, environment-variables, args

In my `build.gradle` I have a task:

```
run {
  dependsOn ':jar'
  args = [ 'run', project.mainVerticleName, '-cluster', "-launcher-class=$mainClassName", '-Denvironment=development' ]
}
```

I want to specify command-line args and read them in my class.

I tried:

```
.\gradlew.bat run -Dhttpport=8825 -Phttpport=8825
```

but the lines in my class:

```
log.info "port = ${System.getProperty( 'httpport' )}"
log.info "port = ${System.getenv( 'httpport' )}"
```

log `null`s for both cases.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
.\gradlew.bat run -Dhttpport=8825
```

you are passing *system properties* to the gradle itself, not to the process it will start. To make it work this way you need to configure `run` as follows:

```
run {
  dependsOn ':jar'
  args = [ 'run', project.mainVerticleName, '-cluster', "-launcher-class=$mainClassName", '-Denvironment=development' ]
  systemProperties System.properties
}
```

and:

```
.\gradlew.bat run -Dhttpport=8825
```

You can also configure system properties using project properties (`-P`) so:

```
run {
  dependsOn ':jar'
  args = [ 'run', project.mainVerticleName, '-cluster', "-launcher-class=$mainClassName", '-Denvironment=development' ]
  systemProperties [httpport:project.httpport]
}
```

and then:

```
.\gradlew.bat run -Phttpport=8825
```